# Issue using Grails addTo()

Tags: arrays, object, grails, groovy, join

I have the following within a controller action:

```
params['selectedOnes[]'].each {
        def schol = Scholarship.findById(it)
        applicant.addToScholarships(schol)
        applicant.save()
    }
```

my applicant class is set up like so:

```
class Applicant {
    //unneeded information
    static hasMany = [scholarships:Scholarship]
}
```

I don't exactly understand how to fix the following error I get from the above:

---

### No signature of method: scholarshipSystem.Applicant.addToScholarships() is applicable for argument types: (scholarshipSystem.Scholarship) values: [scholarshipSystem.Scholarship : 284]

What's the difference between (scholarshipSystem.Scholarship) and [scholarshipSystem.Scholarship : 284]. Isn't it expecting a scholarship object, and that is what i'm padding into the addTo()? Thanks for any help

If it makes much of a difference, I am using Grails 2.2.4

Comment: what is `schol`?  did you mean `blah`? it would make reading the code a lot easier, if you would either "blahify" all or none.

Comment: this is just the syntax of the missing method error message `types: (types here) values: [value.toString()... here]`

Comment: Fixed up. and how do I fix this?

Comment: @connormoore `addToBlahs`?

Comment: @tim_yates missed fixing that. Still confused on the issue and how to fix it.